# why php == not working on artisan tinker laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

As I title I trying to get data `equal id` with `==` but its result empty array, did I miss a thing?...

```
➜  page php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.8 (PHP 7.1.16 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $page = App\PageAtribut::where('page_id', '<', 2)->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2858
     all: [
       App\PageAtribut {#2844
         id: 1,
         page_id: 1,
         watchable_id: 1,
         watchable_type: "App\Category",
         created_at: "2018-09-11 11:03:20",
         updated_at: "2018-09-11 11:03:20",
       },
       App\PageAtribut {#2861
         id: 2,
         page_id: 1,
         watchable_id: 2,
         watchable_type: "App\User",
         created_at: "2018-09-11 11:03:40",
         updated_at: "2018-09-11 11:03:40",
       },
     ],
   }
>>> $page = App\PageAtribut::where('page_id', '==', 1)->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2846
     all: [],
   }
>>>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `=` nor `==`, `App\PageAtribut::where('page_id', 1)` should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a single one, `=`. There is no such thing as `==` in laravel eloquent.

Comment: yea thats work, i din't expect that. in php == is equal and === is identical. in laravel both use = equal and identical ?...

Comment: That's not Laravel/PHP specific. Eloquent translates to SQL where `=` is used

Comment: @DickyRaambo when it comes to eloquent queries, only a single = is available. However, in this case there is no need for an equal sign at all. You can remove it completely!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single '='. The comparison rules used in the where close are those of mysql and not of php.